# How to automatically include conda package in all environments, including new ones

Tags: terminal, conda

I would like to be able to install a `conda` package universally, so that it is present in all environments, both existing ones and newly created ones. I know that generally this is considered a bad idea, but in this particular case I don't think it is. My specific use case is that I don't have `sudo` access, and I'm using `conda` as my package manager, and I want to have `htop`, a package in conda-forge, available everywhere in my terminal. `conda install -c conda-forge htop` only installs `htop` in the current environment, which means I would have to install `htop` in every environment I use. Is it possible to install `htop` so that it's available regardless of the specific environment I have activated?

Comment: Is `htop` a Python package that you import from within the Python interpreter? Or is it just an exectuable? If the latter, you can just install it in the base environment and it should be available all the time, since the `bin` directory for the base environment doesn't leave the `PATH` (I don't think)

Comment: @darthbith It's just an executable. However I'm using the "new style" of adding conda to the environment introduced in in 4.4 (https://github.com/conda/conda/releases/tag/4.4.0) where you `source` a `conda.sh` script and then `conda activate base` in your `~/.bashrc`, so I think only the currently active `conda` environment is on my `PATH`.

Comment: This is my `PATH` with an environment activated: `/Users/bryan/miniconda3/envs/nikola/bin:...:/Users/bryan/miniconda3/bin:...` so at least for me, the base environment remains on the `PATH`... in fact, I think it has to because the `conda` executable is only installed in the base environment

Comment: Yep, I think you're right. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the package you're trying to install will install an executable (and not a Python package; not sure about packages for other languages), then installing the package into the `base` environment is sufficient to make it available in every environment. This is because the `/path/to/base/env/bin` is always on your `$PATH` variable (otherwise, `conda` itself would have to be installed in every environment).

I don't know of a way to install a Python package automatically into every environment.